# App downloads big data again on every start

Tags: permissions, downloading, data-transfer

I have changed many of the permissions (especially by Play Store and Play Store Services). Now many apps works unusual and many doesn't work but doesn't give any understandable error.

One of them is a game "World of Tanks Blitz". Whenever I open the app, it asks for Google account login and then it starts to download the big data like GBs for every tank.

How can I fix or at least how can I understand the problem exactly?

Comment: If the game needs more data assets, I don't see how you would restrict it. Let it do its things

Comment: But on every start, it was getting the same data assets. I gave all permissions to Google Play Store, for now it looks like working properly. It seems like data assets are stored dependently on the Google account.

Comment: What do you mean with "changed many of the permissions"? Anyway this seem to be an app specific problem (bug in the app). Contact the author of the app, describe the problem and ask how to fix it.

Comment: I bought the phone a few days ago. I was checking/playing with the permissions. I saw that there are too many permissions for only Google Play Store and Google Play Store Services. I have taken many of the permissions. I don't remember exactly what permissions because I thought: if there is an error, it will show or ask what the permissions are required. But I didn't get any info from Google Play Store or Services. This game and another one did the same thing; asked login on every start, this looks solved now. Also Duolingo app cannot get my voice even though I gave all permissions to the app.